# Time Difference Split in hour intervals excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

This one is a thinker!

I have the below data set:

[Data http://im61.gulfup.com/AkqnzH.png](http://im61.gulfup.com/AkqnzH.png)

My goal is to get the time difference and split it into hour intervals. i.e. how much time was spent by each person in each hour as below:

[Table http://im45.gulfup.com/UupkLe.png](http://im45.gulfup.com/UupkLe.png)

So the end result should look like this:
[Result http://im44.gulfup.com/WNl5Z6.png](http://im44.gulfup.com/WNl5Z6.png)

Covering the fist scenario is pretty easy:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For MyRow = 2 To LastRow

If Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & MyRow).Value, "hh") = Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & MyRow).Value, "hh") Then

    Set oLookin = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange
    sLookFor = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & MyRow)
    Set oFound = oLookin.Find(What:=sLookFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not oFound Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(oFound.Row, (Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & MyRow).Value, "hh")) + 1).Value = _
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & MyRow).Value - Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & MyRow).Value
    End If
End If

Next MyRow

End Sub
```

However covering the second the third scenarios is where I am find it challenging. How do I go about if the "Time In" hour is not the same as "Time Out". And then how do I split the hours and stop at 00:00:00 as subtracting 00:10:00 from 17:00:09 will give you #############.

I have been trying to figure out a solution, even thought of using a class module somehow? But haven't been able to figure it out :(

Help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any date? As you know date is a date and time part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That one was a thinker! Here's another option that accomplishes your goal using only VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim ws1         As Worksheet
Dim ws2         As Worksheet
Dim LastRow     As Long
Dim MyRow       As Long
Dim oLookin     As Range
Dim sLookFor    As String
Dim oFound      As Range
Dim hour1       As Long
Dim hour2       As Long
Dim minute1     As Long
Dim minute2     As Long
Dim second1     As Long
Dim second2     As Long
Dim curCol      As Long
Dim curTime     As Single

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For MyRow = 2 To LastRow

Set oLookin = ws2.UsedRange
sLookFor = ws1.Range("A" & MyRow)
Set oFound = oLookin.Find(What:=sLookFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

If Not oFound Is Nothing Then
    curCol = Hour(ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value) + 2
    hour1 = Hour(ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value)
    'If the second hour is less than the first hour, then the time went past midnight, so add 24 hours to the second hour so it can be subtracted properly.
    If Hour(ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value) < hour1 Then
        hour2 = Hour(ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value) + 24
    Else: hour2 = Hour(ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value)
    End If

    'If the hour of the first time value is not equal to the hour of the second time value, then loop through the hours until you get to the second hour and put in the corresponding times.
    If hour1 <> hour2 Then
        minute1 = Minute(ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value)
        minute2 = Minute(ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value)
        second1 = Second(ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value)
        second2 = Second(ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value)
        'Loop until the current column represents the second hour.
        Do Until curCol = hour2 + 2 
            'This converts the minutes and seconds of the first time value to a decimal and subtracts it from 1 so you get the time that was used to the end of that hour.
            curTime = 1 - ((minute1 / 60) + (second1 / 3600)) 
            'If the current column is equal to the first hour, use the TimeSerial and Fix functions to convert the decimal back into "h:mm:ss" format.
            If curCol - 2 = hour1 Then
                ws2.Cells(oFound.Row, curCol).Value = TimeSerial(Fix(curTime), Fix((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60), Fix((((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60) - Fix((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60)) * 60))
            'If the current column is not equal to the first hour, put a value of "1:00:00" into the cell.
            Else: ws2.Cells(oFound.Row, curCol).Value = TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
            End If 
            'Go to the next column.
            curCol = curCol + 1
        Loop
        'After you get to the second hour, get only the minutes and seconds of the second time value in decimal format.
        curTime = (minute2 / 60) + (second2 / 3600)
        'Use the TimeSerial and Fix functions to convert the decimal back into "h:mm:ss" format.
        ws2.Cells(oFound.Row, curCol).Value = TimeSerial(Fix(curTime), Fix((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60), Fix((((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60) - Fix((curTime - Fix(curTime)) * 60)) * 60))
    'If the first hour is equal to the second hour, subtract the two time values and put the difference in the correct column.
    Else
        ws2.Cells(oFound.Row, curCol).Value = ws1.Range("C" & MyRow).Value - ws1.Range("B" & MyRow).Value
    End If
End If

Next MyRow

End Sub
```

Note that, if the time goes past midnight, it will continue to fill in the times after column Y. This can be modified to make it stop at column Y if you need.

Comment: Thanks, this works! But it would be appreciated if you can explain your code a bit :)

Comment: Glad I could help! I've added comments to my code to explain it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with 50 lines of VBA code when a simple formula will do the trick?

[image]

`=IF($C4>$B4,IF($B4<=D$1,IF($C4>=D$2,TIME(1,0,0),IF($C4<=D$1,"",$C4-D$1)),IF($B4>=D$2,"",IF($C4>=D$2,D$2-$B4,$C4-$B4))),IF($B4<=D$1,TIME(1,0,0),IF($B4>=D$2,"",D$2-$B4)))`

Copy formula down and to right, and change number format to Time.

Note the two helper rows 1 and 2, with start and end times of each hour interval. In row 3 I reconstituted your headers with this formula:

```
=TEXT(D1,"hh:mm")&"-"&TEXT(D2,"hh:mm")
```

If you don't like those helper rows, you can, in principle do away with them and extract the time values from the header text using the `TIMEVALUE` and `SEARCH` functions. To do so, replace each instance of `D$1` in the first formula above with

```
TIMEVALUE(LEFT(D3,SEARCH("-",D$3)))
```

and each instance of `D$1` with

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(D3,SEARCH("-",D3)+1,50))
```

But in my opinion, doing this would be a bit ridiculous.

Note that this formula can't deal with times beyond the `23:00-00:00` column i.e. the next day. But it can easily be expanded to do so and this is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Change the column headers to the hour the period starts then use this formula:

```
=GetTime($B2,$C2,D$1)
```

Copy that formula across all area.  **AND SET THE CELL's NUMBER FORMAT TO "custom" "[h]:mm:ss"**

Here is the code for the UDF:

```
Public Function GetTime(TimeIn As Date, TimeOut As Date, CurHr As Date) As Date

Dim mins As Integer, secs As Integer

Select Case True
    Case Hour(TimeIn) < Hour(CurHr) And (Hour(TimeOut) > Hour(CurHr) Or Hour(TimeOut) < 1)
        GetTime = TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
        Exit Function
    Case Hour(TimeIn) = Hour(CurHr) And Hour(TimeOut) = Hour(CurHr)
        mins = DateDiff("s", TimeIn, TimeOut) Mod 60
        secs = DateDiff("s", TimeIn, TimeOut) - (DateDiff("s", TimeIn, TimeOut) Mod 60) * 60
        GetTime = TimeSerial(0, mins, secs)
    Case Hour(TimeIn) < Hour(CurHr) And Hour(TimeOut) = Hour(CurHr)
        mins = DateDiff("s", CurHr, TimeOut) Mod 60
        secs = DateDiff("s", CurHr, TimeOut) - (DateDiff("s", CurHr, TimeOut) Mod 60) * 60
        GetTime = TimeSerial(0, mins, secs)
    Case (Hour(TimeOut) > Hour(CurHr) Or Hour(TimeOut) < 1) And Hour(TimeIn) = Hour(CurHr)
        mins = DateDiff("s", TimeIn, DateAdd("h", 1, CurHr)) Mod 60
        secs = DateDiff("s", TimeIn, DateAdd("h", 1, CurHr)) - (DateDiff("s", TimeIn, DateAdd("h", 1, CurHr)) Mod 60) * 60
        GetTime = TimeSerial(0, mins, secs)
    Case Else
        GetTime = 0
End Select

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I prefer something all VBA without UDFs :)